# Replacing null values in a list with values of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have two lists

```
lis1 = [12,34,56,89]
lis2 = [10,34,90,108,None,None,None,None]
```

How do I replace `None` values with values of `lis1` without creating any new list?

The end result should be

```
lis2 = [10,34,90,108,12,34,56,89]
```

So far what I tried

```
lis2 = [i for j in lis2 for i in lis1 if j is None]
```

But this gives me an incorrect list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
In [870]: lis2[lis2.index(None):] = lis1

In [871]: lis2
Out[871]: [10, 34, 90, 108, 12, 34, 56, 89]
```

Subslice assignment. The assumption here is that `lis2` has as many `None` values as `lis1` has elements and that they all lie at the end.

---

To break it down:

1. `lis2.index(None)` returns the first index of `None` in the list

   ```
   In [873]: lis2.index(None)
   Out[873]: 4
   ```
2. You can obtain a subslice of `lis1` like this:

   ```
   In [874]: lis2[lis2.index(None):]
   Out[874]: [None, None, None, None]
   ```
3. Just reassign `lis2` to this slice.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Can you explain me the first line of your code?

Comment: @SouvikRay Edited my answer with explanation.

Comment: @coldspeed What is `None` is shuffled in lis2?

Comment: Wow it solved my problem!But even I am curious to @voidpro question

Comment: @voidpro It'll fail :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.

```
> lis1 = [12,34,56,89]
> lis2 = [10,34,90,108,None,None,None,None]
> lis2 = [x for x in lis2 if x is not None]
> lis2
=> [10, 34, 90, 108]
> lis2 += lis1
> lis2
=> [10, 34, 90, 108, 12, 34, 56, 89]
```

First remove all `None` from `lis2`. Then extend `lis2` with `lis1`

Comment: This does not remove any elements from `lis2`. It simply creates a new list and assigns it to the `lis2` variable.

Comment: @PaulRooney thats right. `lis2` would be reassigned with new values.

Comment: Yup if memory space is not an issue,even this could be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

(Expanding on COLDSPEED's answer, which is cleaner if all the Nones come at the end of the list.)

```
# Replace Nones in list 2 with elements from list 1
> lis1 = [2, 3, 6, 8]
> lis2 = [1, None, None, 4, 5, None, 7, None]

# Index of next element to use from list 1
> j = 0

> for i in range(len(lis2)):
    if lis2[i] == None:
        lis2[i] = lis1[j]  # Replace a None with something from list 1
        j += 1  # Use the following element next time

> lis2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Again, you'll have to do some checking if it's not guaranteed that the length of list 1 is the same as the number of `None`s in list 2.

Comment: What if the number of `None` in `lis2` is greater than the number of elements in `lis1`?

Comment: You would get a `list index out of range` error. If you wanted to make sure that didn't happen you could `break` out of the loop once `j == len(lis1)`.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way:

```
lis2 = [1, None, None, 4, 5, None, 7, None]
lis1 = [2, 3, 6, 8]
list2 =[i if i else lis1.pop(0) for i in lis2]
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```